# What is the difference between <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and numpy.ndarray?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have been doing some calculations using numpy arrays and have arrived at the question of what is the difference between:

`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and `numpy.ndarray`

I have noticed that the following operation only works on `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`:
`(arrray == 1).sum()`

Why is that so?

Comment: I obtain some data from an API call in that format...

Comment: What's `arrray` when it does not work?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference; they're identical.

`numpy.ndarray` is the actual type of numpy arrays; `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` is the *string represention* ot `numpy.ndarray`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> print(type(a) == np.ndarray)
True

>>> np.ndarray
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> print(type(a))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> str(type(a))
"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"

>>> repr(type(a))
"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"
```

Python interpreters such as IPython and Jupyter (which underneath are actually the same thing) will trim of the `<class '...' >` part and only show the type itself when you enter the type the into interpreter, e.g. **`ipython`**:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:44) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.ndarray
Out[2]: numpy.ndarray
```

...versus `python` (the builtin interpreter):

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:44) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ndarray
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

...but they're the exact same type.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are confusing numpy arrays and python lists.  I/we often talk about a `numpy` array, meaning actually an object of class/type `np.ndarray`.

```
In [144]: a = [1, 2, 3]         # a list
In [145]: b = np.array(a)       # an array
In [146]: type(a), type(b)
Out[146]: (list, numpy.ndarray)
```

Your expression works with the array, but not the list:

```
In [147]: (b == 1).sum()
Out[147]: 1
In [148]: (a == 1).sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [148] in <module>
    (a == 1).sum()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'

In [149]: b == 1
Out[149]: array([ True, False, False])
In [150]: a == 1
Out[150]: False
```

Note that I created `b` with `np.array()`.  There is a `np.ndarray` function, but we don't usually use it - it's a low level creator that most of us don't need.  A useful starting page:

https://numpy.org/doc/1.22/user/basics.creation.html